Why LiftingAccum for MonadAccum but no auto lifting?
In the design of Control.Monad.Accum, I noticed that for a new Monad transformer t, one typically has to define the instance via LiftingAccum. However, I believe it would be more straightforward to define an automatic lifting mechanism that traverses the outer Monad transformers.
For instance, consider the following definition:
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}
  (MonadTrans t, Monad m, MonadAccum w m) =>
    MonadAccum w (t m) where
  accum :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m, MonadAccum w m) => (w -> (a, w)) -> t m a
  accum = lift . accum

I think this approach would be more convenient for users who want to adopt a new Monad Transformer (say, LogicT). Is there a reason that precluded the designer of MonadAccum from adopting this easy implementation?
The implementation was compiled and worked as expected.

Overlapping instances are fragile. Putting overlapping instances into a library seems like a good way to cause subtle bugs that are very difficult to track down.

Thanks! That seems to be a very good reason!

The usual issue is with discrepancies in instance availability. If one module generates code that statically chooses this instance because no other matching instance is available, but another module generates code that statically chooses an overlapping instance, then you will have a problem when you link those two modules together. (I don't actually know off-hand if this situation is realizable but it certainly seems like it ought to be.)

I have also read about this warning case on the GHC page. But it seems that it is "unimplemented"? My understanding is that when compiling a module, its dependent modules will be compiled first and the situation, if no incoherence is allowed, will lead to an error message stating conflicting instances? On the other hand, later modules will have more information on which instance to use seems quite natural?
